# Make "M-x repeat" Ignore Movement Commands

Tags: commands, events, repeat

Is there a standard way to make `M-x repeat` ignore movement commands or does it require custom elisp?

I read a [Mastering Emacs blog post about repeating commands][1] and immediately started using "repeat" regularly in my workflow. One annoying quirk though is that in the post it says "the M-x repeat command will repeat the last action, but it does ignore input events, like moving around" and in my experience that isn't true by default.

For example using emacs 29.1, if you have two lines:

```
apples
bananas
```

With the point before "apples" if I run `delete-word`, `next-line`, and `M-x repeat` the expected behavior would be to repeat `delete-word`. Instead, `next-line` is repeated.

I looked through repeat.el and found the custom variable `repeat-too-dangerous`, which is documented as `"Commands too dangerous to repeat with \\[repeat]."` I can write some elisp to add movement commands to this variable, but that feels wonky.

Is there a more straightforward approach that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Drew's answer below I wrote the following code that works for my purpose. Sharing here in hope it is helpful for others!

```
;; Make M-x repeat ignore movement commands                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
(defvar my/last-repeatable-command nil                                                                                                                                                                             
  "Copy of last-repeatable-command that ignores my/repeat-commands-to-ignore")                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
(defvar my/repeat-commands-to-ignore                                                                                                                                                                               
  '(my/repeat next-line end-of-line left-char right-char                                                                                                                                                           
              previous-line beginning-of-line beginning-of-visual-line)                                                                                                                                            
  "List of commands for my/last-repeatable-command to ignore."                                                                                                                                                     
  )                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
(defun my/repeat (repeat-arg)                                                                                                                                                                                      
  "Modified version of repeat that ignore commands in my/repeat-commands-to-ignore."                                                                                                                               
  (interactive "P")                                                                                                                                                                                                
  (when (null repeat-arg)                                                                                                                                                                                          
    (setq repeat-arg last-prefix-arg))                                                                                                                                                                             
  (let '(last-repeatable-command my/last-repeatable-command)                                                                                                                                                       
    (call-interactively 'repeat t (vector repeat-arg))))                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
(defun my/save-last-repeatable-command ()                                                                                                                                                                          
  "Set to last-repeatable-command if value not in my/repeat-commands-to-ignore."                                                                                                                                   
  (if (not (member last-repeatable-command my/repeat-commands-to-ignore))                                                                                                                                          
      (setq my/last-repeatable-command last-repeatable-command)))                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
(add-hook 'pre-command-hook 'my/save-last-repeatable-command)                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
(global-set-key [remap repeat] 'my/repeat)
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone else will hopefully answer your real question, which is about how to do what you want to do.

It's not very clear to me what you really want to do, or why.  In particular, if you want to repeat `delete-word` then just use `C-x z` after you use that command.  If you used it prior to the last command (which is, e.g., `next-line`) then just repeat it once (hit a key bound to it or use `M-x delete-word`) and then use `C-z z`.

(My crystal ball whispers that perhaps you're really looking for a keyboard macro, but it's pretty foggy.  Or you can save `delete-word` as the value of `last-repeatable-command` and then use `C-z z`.)

---

This answer will at least try to clear up what's meant by mention of *ignoring commands bound to input events*.  (I think Mickey's blog text is incorrect/misguided in saying that the "input events" that are ignored include "moving around" commands. They don't.)

---

From the doc string:

> `repeat` is an autoloaded interactive Lisp function in ‘repeat.el’.
>
> It is bound to `C-x z`.
>
> `(repeat REPEAT-ARG)`
>
> Repeat most recently executed command.
>
> If `REPEAT-ARG` is non-`nil` (interactively, with a prefix argument),
> supply a prefix argument to that command.  Otherwise, give the
> command the same prefix argument it was given before, if any.
>
> If this command is invoked by a multi-character key sequence, it
> can then be repeated by repeating the final character of that
> sequence.  This behavior can be modified by the global variable
> `repeat-on-final-keystroke`.
>
> `repeat` **ignores commands bound to input events**.  Hence the term
> "most recently executed command" shall be read as "most
> recently executed **command not bound to an input event**".

What that doc really means by that last paragraph is that the command `self-insert-command` that's bound to self-inserting chars that you type is not taken as the last command (it is ignored by `repeat`), so it is not repeated.

More precisely, all commands that are bound to input events are similarly ignored.  This means that the value of `last-command-event` is not used as the command to be repeated.  This is the doc of that variable: `Last input event that was part of a command.`  The Elisp manual, node [Command Loop Info](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Command-Loop-Info.html) is of a bit more help:

> Variable: `last-command-event`
> This variable is set to the last input event that was read by the
> command loop as part of a command.  **The principal use of this
> variable is in `self-insert-command`**, which uses it to decide which
> character to insert.
>
> ```
> last-command-event
> ;; Now use ‘C-u C-x C-e’ to evaluate that.
>    ⇒ 5
> ```
>
> The value is 5 because that is the ASCII code for `C-e`.

In `repeat.el` you'll find a bit of explanation of why things are done the way they are in this regard.  Here is one such comment:

```
;; With Emacs 22.2 the variable `last-repeatable-command' stores the
;; most recently executed command that was not bound to an input event.
;; `repeat' now repeats that command instead of `real-last-command' to
;; avoid a "... must be bound to an event with parameters" error.
```

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful and illluminating. At minimum I'm glad that I'm not crazy and that the blog post was misleading.

As for use cases, the example above is contrived to show what I mean. I'm a former vim user so a common pattern is to do a reasonably complex command (like zap-to-char up to a paren) and then hit "." to repeat it on various non-consecutive lines.

`last-repeatable-command` looks like what I need. I'll try to advise whatever function sets it to ignore next-line and previous-line. Or adopt the emacs pattern of more aggresively using macros :)

Comment: Based on your response I figured out a solution. I updated the original question with the code.

Comment: Please **don't do that** (put an answer in your question). *Instead, post it as an* **answer**. And yes, you can accept your own answer. Q&A should be separate, for searching (googling etc.) and for clarity. Thx.

Comment: Sure thing, just moved it down into a separate comment and marked as the answer.